# Как получить историю сообщений из группы телеграм

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Перерыл всю документацию aiogram, на котором пишу телеграм бота, но никак не найду способ получения истории сообщений и поиска сообщений по user_id в публичной группе, в которой состоит бот. Позволяет ли aiogram или любая другая библиотека реализовать такую функцию? Или придется использовать бд?

Comment: Вообще используя именно `Telegram bot API` - невозможно получить такую историю, но можно воспользоваться другим подходом, создавая собственный клиент через `MTProto api` (библиотека `telethon` подойдёт), вот там уже есть возможность получить списки сообщений и итерироваться между ними

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример кода, закомментировал каждую строчку

```
import telebot  # импортируем модуль telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot('your_bot_token')  # создаем экземпляр класса TeleBot с указанием токена вашего бота

@bot.message_handler(commands=['history'])  # определяем обработчик команды /history
def get_history(message):
    chat_id = message.chat.id  # получаем ID чата, из которого была отправлена команда
    messages = bot.history(chat_id, limit=100)  # получаем последние 100 сообщений из чата
    for message in messages:  # проходимся по каждому сообщению из списка сообщений
        bot.send_message(chat_id, message.text)  # отправляем текст сообщения обратно в чат

bot.polling()  # запускаем бота
```